# Cannot add a launch shortcut (Eclipse Plug-in)

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm making a simple extra java app launcher for Eclipse 3.2 (JBuilder 2007-8) for internal use.

So I looked up all the documentations related, including this one [The Launching Framework from eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html) and have managed to make everything else working with the exception of the launch shortcut.

[image]

This is the part of my plugin.xml.

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
  <shortcut
        category="mycompany.javalaunchext.launchConfig"
        class="mycompany.javalaunchext.LaunchShortcut"
        description="launchshortcutsdescription"
        icon="icons/k2mountain.png"
        id="mycompany.javalaunchext.launchShortcut"
        label="Java Application Ext."
        modes="run, debug">
     <perspective
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     </perspective>
     <perspective
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaHierarchyPerspective">
     </perspective>
     <perspective
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaBrowsingPerspective">
     </perspective>
     <perspective
           id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective">
     </perspective>
  </shortcut>
```

The configuration name in the category section is correct and the class in the class section, i believe, is correctly implemented. (basically copied from org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut)

---

I'm really not sure if I'm supposed to write a follow-up here but let me clarify my question more.
I've extended org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut. 
Plus, I've added my own logger to constructors and methods, but the class seems like it's never even instantiating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add `contextualLaunch` under `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts`.

The old way seems like it's deprecated a long ago.

For other people who are working on the same subject,
you might want to extend `org.eclipse.ui.commands` and bindings, too.

I cannot choose this answer but this is the answer that I (the questioner) was looking for.

Comment: Hi, is there a chance you can post the plugin.xml text of the contextual launcher that you used. I appear to be having the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi @Chris sorry this question was posted years ago and I don't have the code with me anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

You class should implement ILaunchShortcut.
Check out the [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/ILaunchShortcut.html).

What exception are you getting?  Check the error log.